# Is there a way to get combinations for a set of tuples?

Tags: python, combinations

I have a set of tuples:

```
(1, 3, 6)
(5, 2, 4)
...
(8, 1, 9)
```

I can get combinations of middle (or first or last) values whose sum is below a certain value:

```
def func(tuples, maxVal):
    values = [i[1] for i in tuples]
    result = [seq for s in range(len(values), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(values, s) if sum(seq) <= maxVal]
    print(result)
```

but i'd like to be able to keep track of which tuples the values came from, so instead of just returning sets of values with appropriate sum, i want to return whole tuples which those values came from. Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
from itertools import combinations

def func(tuples, maxVal):
    return [seq for s in range(len(tuples), 0, -1)
                for seq in combinations(tuples, s)
                if sum(t[1] for t in seq) <= maxVal]

tuplesset = {(1, 3, 6), (5, 2, 4), (8, 1, 9)}
print(func(tuplesset, 4))
```

The printout from that is

```
[((1, 3, 6), (8, 1, 9)), ((5, 2, 4), (8, 1, 9)), ((1, 3, 6),), ((5, 2, 4),), ((8, 1, 9),)]
```

which seems to be correct.

The main differences between my routine and yours is that I leave out the `values` variable (the middle values in your tuples) and have the expression `sum(t[1] for t in seq)` rather than `sum(seq)` for summing the middle values of the tuples. I also broke your one long line into multiple shorter lines for legibility and to follow PEP8 better.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I had a feeling the solution was close, but looking at the long list comprehension line (which I found in some other SO solution and modified) just made more confused, I'm still learning %\ . Thank you for breaking it up for me too! This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary mapped to pairs if you really want to save the tuples instead of just saving the indices:

{(x, x, x) : ( (z,z,z), (y,y,y) ), ... }